# Calculating Lie Algebra

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, lie-algebras

I am studying Quantum Field Theory and I am having some difficulties with the concept of a Lie Algebra.

My understanding is that a Lie Algebra is a vector space equipped with the commutator $[x,y] = xy - yx$. However, I've often come across questions such as: "calculate the Lie Algebra of $SU(2)$".

I'm not sure how one can calculate such things? Are there any good (and hopefully shortish) references that I can use to understand this?

Comment: It's unclear what your definition of Lie algebra means (what is $xy$?) but you should look up Lie groups. The basic reason we study Lie algebras is that every Lie group has an associated Lie algebra that says a lot about it.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan $xy$ is the matrix product of the representation of two elements $x$ and $y$ that are members of the vector space. The problem that I'm having is that there appears to be a lot of mathematics around Lie Algebra/Lie Groups that is superfluous to my understanding of QFT. I'm looking for a reference to help clarify what I need to know I guess!

Comment: It sounds like you are using "vector space" to mean a subspace of the space of matrices. The mathematical usage of "vector space" is considerably broader than this.

Answer (score 2):

Lie algebras of matrices have a Lie bracket given by $[x,y]=xy-yx$, but abstract Lie algebras need not consist of matrices. Then the term $xy$ has a priori no meaning. There is a (difficult) theorem by Ado and Iwasawa, that every finite-dimensional Lie algebra over a field $K$ can be realised by matrices. The references you will need, I suppose, are called "[Lie groups and Lie algebras for physicists](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/9814616907)". There are plenty of such books.

Answer (score 2):

I think about Lie algebras by building upon other concepts, and specific examples of them:

1. Group
2. Lie Group
3. Lie Algebra

Speaking a bit broadly:

A **group** is a set of *discrete* elements with an operation that takes any element in the group to a unique another element.  There is an inverse operation (that takes you back), an identity element, and a few other technical requirements.  A simple example is the group of transformations that yield a square:  you can leave it alone (identity transformation), rotate by $+90^\circ$, or $180^\circ$ or flip along a vertical line through the center, or along a horizontal line through the center, a diagonal line through the center, and so on.  You have *discrete* transformations and the operations are "closed".

A **Lie group** is a *continuous* group, where the transformations are continuous.  Think of the transformations of a sphere.  You can rotate by any real-valued angle (e.g., $26.984^\circ$) around an axis pointed in an arbitrary direction (e.g., a vector $\{ -.2, \pi, .8777... \}$).  Any such rotation yields the sphere.  And these rotations can be composited:  Do transformation 1 then transformation 2 and it is equivalent to a single transformation 3.  You can have *infinitessimal* transformations, and the operations are "closed".

A **Lie algebra** is the mathematics that governs such continuous transformations.  Any Lie Group has an association Lie Algebra.  Formally, you need a vector space and a non-associative "multiplication" operation.  Think of the sphere.  The transformations (transformation 1 * transformation 2) * transformation 3 need not be the same as transformation 1 * (transformation 2 * transformation 3).  You can express this with a Lie Algebra (whose elements are the rotations).  If you work with rotations of a 5-dimensional sphere (for instance), the Lie Algebra will differ from that for a 3-sphere or 2-sphere.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned, there are plenty of books about Lie groups and Lie algebras - it's a mathematically mature subject with lots of different strands. May I suggest, if you want a quick overview from a perspective that may be more on your wavelength, that you try to pick up a copy of [Physics from Symmetry](http://www.springer.com/gb/book/9783319192000) by J. Schwintenberg. It is isn't a mathematics book; it isn't theorem, proof, corollary, proof etc. It is just full of ideas and examples of applying Lie theory to physics; it even gets on to discussing quantum field theory too!